# get all child nodes value using foreach

Tags: c#, .net, xml

```
<R>
<tests>
<test language="en"> hello </test>
<test language="it"> ciao </test>
<test language="hu"> szia </test>
<test language="es"> ola </test>
</tests>
</R>
```

The above part of XML is contained in a (XML) file. I do want foreach test xml element to read and get the XML value.

I tried something like this:

```
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(theXmlURLpath);

    foreach (var iDescription in xdoc.XPathSelectElements("R/tests"))
    {
         string lang = iDescription.Attribute("language").Value; // en / it / hu / es
         string text= iDescription.Value; // hello or ciao ...
         switch(iLang)
         {
          case "en":
          // do something
          break;
          case "it":
          // do something
          break;
          case "hu":
          // do something
          break;
          case "es":
          // do something
          break;
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XPath does not select the `<test/>` elements, but the `<tests/>` parent element.

Try

```
xdoc.XPathSelectElements("R/tests/test")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix straight xml (XmlDocument) with xml linq (XDocument).  Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication29
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

                foreach (var iDescription in xdoc.Descendants("test"))
                {
                     string lang = (string)iDescription.Attribute("language"); // en / it / hu / es
                     string text= (string)iDescription; // hello or ciao ...
                     switch(lang)
                     {
                          case "en":
                          // do something
                          break;
                          case "it":
                          // do something
                          break;
                          case "hu":
                          // do something
                          break;
                          case "es":
                          // do something
                          break;
                     }
                 }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: He is not mixing XML and LINQ2XML. He is working exclusively in XDocument.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(theXmlURLpath);

        var testElements = xdoc.Root.Element("tests").Elements("test");

        foreach (var testElement in testElements)
        {
            var lang = testElement.Attribute("language").Value; // en / it / hu / es
            var text = testElement.Value; // hello or ciao ...
            switch (lang)
            {
                case "nl":
                    // do something
                    break;
                case "d":
                    // do something
                    break;
                case "gb":
                    // do something
                    break;
                case "fr":
                    // do something
                    break;
                case "esp":
                    // do something
                    break;
                case "it":
                    // do something
                    break;
            }
        }
```